# Send large text with API call in React native

Tags: reactjs, api, native

For my react native app I have to send and fetch large cipher text with an API call, but I'm getting error with status code 414. so is there any other way to achieve this. Please help me,
Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP 414 code means "URI Too Long".
I guess you are providing the text as a url query parameter.

Add the text inside the request body instead of in the url and then you should have no problem :).

Example code if you are using node-fetch (the default fetch function in react-native):

How I guess you are currently doing the request:

```
let myText = "This is a long text";
let res = await fetch(`https://myapi.com/uploadText?text=${myText}`, {
    method: "POST"
});
```

How you should be doing the request:

```
let myText = "This is a long text";
let res = await fetch("https://myapi.com/uploadText", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        text: myText
    })
});
```